# Finding all objects in an image based on color

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am looking for a way to take an image and get masks of all objects in it by color. My goal is to be able to separate similarly colored objects into layers so I can further examine each layer. The plan is to use each mask against the original image to create a histogram of the colors in each object and determine the similarity with other objects in the image. If something is similar enough it will be combined with other objects to form a layer.

The problem is that I can not find a function in opencv to find all objects in an image based on color contiguity. I am sure such an algorithm exists, but it seems to be evading me. Does anyone know of an algorithm or function like this?

Comment: how about: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html?highlight=watershed , it's in python but uses opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method that I have found is [K-means Clustering](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html). This separates the image into different layers based on color. It uses a k-neighbors algorithm to do so. With this I am able to effectively split the image into several layers that are of similar color.

```
#define numClusters 7

cv::Mat src = cv::imread("img0.png");

cv::Mat kMeansSrc(src.rows * src.cols, 3, CV_32F);
//resize the image to src.rows*src.cols x 3
//cv::kmeans expects an image that is in rows with 3 channel columns
//this rearranges the image into (rows * columns, numChannels)
for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
{
    for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++ )
    {
        for( int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
            kMeansSrc.at<float>(y + x*src.rows, z) = src.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[z];
    }
}

cv::Mat labels;
cv::Mat centers;
int attempts = 2;
//perform kmeans on kMeansSrc where numClusters is defined previously as 7
//end either when desired accuracy is met or the maximum number of iterations is reached
cv::kmeans(kMeansSrc, numClusters, labels, cv::TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 8, 1), attempts, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers );

//create an array of numClusters colors
int colors[numClusters];
for(int i = 0; i < numClusters; i++) {
        colors[i] = 255/(i+1);
}

std::vector<cv::Mat> layers;

for(int i = 0; i < numClusters; i++)
{
    layers.push_back(cv::Mat::zeros(src.rows,src.cols,CV_32F));
}

//use the labels to draw the layers
//using the array of colors, draw the pixels onto each label image
for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
{
    for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++ )
    { 
        int cluster_idx = labels.at<int>(y + x*src.rows,0);
        layers[cluster_idx].at<float>(y, x) = (float)(colors[cluster_idx]);;
    }
}

std::vector<cv::Mat> srcLayers;

//each layer to mask a portion of the original image
//this leaves us with sections of similar color from the original image
for(int i = 0; i < numClusters; i++)
{
    layers[i].convertTo(layers[i], CV_8UC1);
    srcLayers.push_back(cv::Mat());
    src.copyTo(srcLayers[i], layers[i]);
}
```

Comment: seems to be a very nice method...can you share the code and your results?

Comment: I realize the namespace handling is a bit whack. I typically don't define namespaces but some of the code I used did. I just didn't edit everything to match styles. Shouldn't be a problem

Comment: thanks for updating it. Is it possible for you to add some more description to the code by putting some more comments...then it will be very helpful for others including me. As, i don't know much about it so, i am hardly able to understand the reason behind your each step. :)

Comment: I cleaned up the code and added more comments. Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Thanks, it seems nice. If i have any other query in future then, i will ask here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you convert the image to the HSV-space (Hue-Saturation-Value). Then make a histogram based on the Hue value to find thresholds online, or define them before (depends if this is a general problem or a given one).

Crate one-channel images for each layer you want to form. (set them as black)

Then then use the HSV-image and mark a layer based on the threshold values. You might want to add some constant thresholds for value and saturation too (to avoid dark and light areas)

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: I understand this but my problem is that I don't really want to have predefined layers. For my application I am looking to detect certain things such as skin where the color/lighting changes with completely dynamic backgrounds. Perhaps I could use some kind of grid-like floodfill function to fill parts of the image and mask them out after filling. With each floodfilled segment perhaps I could then use those as segments for the histogram similarity algorithm. The goal is to be able to differentiate between the background/foreground so that I can can create a color space of the background.

Comment: I see. Sure you can try floodfill, I'm not that costume to that method. There are some threshold algorithms (online) that you can use to set levels as Otsu or simulated annealing. Or use multi-p-tile. You heard of them?

Comment: I have heard of Otsu thresholding but not the other methods. I came across K-means clustering and this seemed to give me the desired output.

Comment: I'm glad you sort it out yourself;) Please provide your answer and close this post.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should proceed in the following proceess:

- Smooth you image if it has too much details.
- find edges
- Find all contours
- Try to find the color of each contour..lets say you want to keep all contours which are red. So, keep only those contours which are red.
- Once you find the contours which you want to keep, then create a mask image based upon the contours you want to keep.
- Using mask image, extract the required objects from the original image.

Comment: I have used a similar method in the past and unfortunately it just doesn't quite work well enough. K-means clustering seemed to give me very good results though. I will post a link.